# how we can use PROFILESTARTDATE in paypal payment form

Tags: paypal-sandbox

can we define PROFILESTARTDATE in payPal form like we mention the BILLINGPERIOD and BILLINGFREQUENCY as t3,p3 () in it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of recurring payment types:

1. Subscriptions
2. Recurring Payments

For difference: [PayPal subscription vs recurring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359442/paypal-subscription-vs-recurring)

---

PROFILESTARTDATE option is only available when you use the recurring payment api.

Comment: thankx for our ans.
can you please tell me where to mention the notify_url in recurring payment APi?

Comment: PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL should work.

More details are on https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/  
If you think this answers your question then you can select this answer as accepted.