# Button pay outstanding amount (subscription)?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

When a recurring payment fails, is there a way to create a button for the subscriber to pay the outstanding amount?

But not as billing or as a separate Pay button; I'd like the payment to go into the recurring payment procedure, so that the recurring acct clears the outstanding amount, and the IPN handling can keep track of subscription payments.

As it is now, a failed payment stays there for 5 days while PP attempts collection 3 times, and only after the 3rd attempt there is an option to collect the outstanding amount manually (but on the business side, not the subscriber's ?).

Tnx.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after navigating the horrible dreadful spaghetti of PP docs (and broken links everywhere like x.com), it seems that having used the WPS subscribe button was the mistake in the first place, as we are stuck with profiles that are useless for the RecurringPayments API.

Unless someone can correct me, it seems better to cancel our subscriptions (hopefully [cancel works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359442/paypal-subscription-vs-recurring): ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus), and start anew with recurring payment express checkout, which can then be handled with EC [API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/)...